# Move or reorder content outside of parent using CSS/Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to reorder content from within a parent container to outside of parent?

I want to move content box 3, 4 & 5 from within content box 2 into content box 0 (which is after 1 & 2)

[image: An illustration of my code]

Note: I'm only targeting mordern browsers (IE10+)

I have a working example or reordering content within the same parent content box.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/calebo/full/HAzyr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Flex items can only be rearranged with their siblings.